# Proof of an explicit formula for $\pi_0(x)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(x)$ denote the prime counting function and $$\pi_0(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\pi(x+\epsilon)+\pi(x-\epsilon)}{2}.$$
I've seen noted in a few references the explicit formula
$$\pi_0(x) = R(x)-\sum_\rho R(x^\rho), \quad x>1,$$
where the sum is over all zeros $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function (the nontrivial zeros taken in conjugate pairs and in order of imaginary part), and where $$R(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(s^{1/n}).$$
See, for example, [Watkins - the "encoding" of the distribution of prime numbers by the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function [common approach]](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/encoding1.htm).
I am wondering if someone can help by providing a proof of this explicit formula for $\pi_0(x)$ (perhaps from some other known explicit formula, e.g., for $\Pi_0(x)$), or else supply a reference that proves it.  I can't find a proof of it in the literature.

EDIT: The explicit formula for $\pi_0(x)$ above likely follows from the  Riemann–von Mangoldt explicit formula for $\Pi_0(x)$ because, for all $x >1$, one has
\begin{align*}
\pi_0(x)  & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\Pi_0(x^{1/n}) \\  
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \left( \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n}) - \sum_\rho \operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{\rho \log x}{n}\right) - \log 2  \right) \\
 & = R(x) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_\rho \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\operatorname{Ei}\left(\frac{\rho \log x}{n}\right),
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$, and then the explicit formula for $\pi_0(x)$ in question follows provided that the sums over $n$ and $\rho$ above can be interchanged with one another.  Thus, my question is: can the two sums in fact be interchanged with one another?

Comment: the formula is due to Riemann, you can find a proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282848/87355

Comment: The end of the MathWorld article at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html states "However, no proof of the equality of (12) appears to exist in the literature (Borwein et al. 2000)", so the status seems somewhat controversial.

Comment: See https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/borwein1.pdf page 4 for the claim.

Comment: @StevenClark.  The Mathworld article claims it's true summing over the nontrivial zeros, but I think you have to sum over all zeros, including the real ones.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker.  The formula isn't proved there. All it says is that it follows from (9) by Mobius inversion, but "with questionable convergence".

Comment: See for example A. E. Ingham, _The distribution of prime numbers_ (1932), Chapter IV: Explicit formulae.

Comment: @BartMichels.  I have that book!  Unfortunately it only proves the explicit formula for $\psi_0$, not for $\Pi_0$, or the hypothetical one for $\pi_0$.